# Селективный ХМЛ индекс на сервере 2008R2

Tags: xml, index, sql-server-2008

Работаю, к сожалению, на 2008 сервере и есть соблазн воспользоваться селективным ХМЛ индексом. Если доверять ссылке:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/xml/selective-xml-indexes-sxi?view=sql-server-2017
То вроде как возможность доступна с 2008 сервера, вот только пространство имен такого синтаксиса не знает.

Может сервер надо как-то патчить или иное, поделитесь информацией пожалуйста :)

Comment: _пространство имен такого синтаксиса не знает_ - что? Уточните.

Comment: CREATE SELECTIVE XML INDEX SXI_index  
ON Tbl(xmlcol)  . в запросе присутствует ключевое слово "SELECTIVE"